# Genetic notations

Tags: genetics, mutations, nomenclature

Genetic testing revealed these two mutations (hypothetically):

IVS11+6G>A and IVS11-4G＞A

Could you please explain every part of this notation, especially "+" and "-" signs.

Comment: have you tried googling first? if not, [this query](https://www.google.com/search?q=IVS11%2B6G%3EA&oq=IVS11%2B6G%3EA&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=how+to+read+mutation+nomenclature) yields a useful page: [Nomenclature for the description of sequence variations](http://www.hgmd.cf.ac.uk/docs/mut_nom.html). **Quote**: 88+1G>T (alternatively IVS2+1G>T) denotes the G to T substitution at nucleotide +1of intron 2, relative to the cDNA positioned between nucleotides 88 and 89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These describe mutations (SNPs) in introns.

IVS stands for intervening sequence (which is another term for intron).

The number following IVS specifies which intron the mutation occurs in (intron 1 follows exon 1, etc).

The +n or -n, where n is an integer, gives the location of the nucleotide. +n counts 3' from the preceding exon whereas -n counts 5' from the following exon. I *think* that the first and last nucleotide of each exon is given position 0 such that, for example, +1 refers to the first nucleotide of the intron and -1 refers to the last.

X>Y, where X and Y are nucleotides, describe what mutation has occurred.

---

IVS11+6G>A means a G to A transition at position +6 of intron 11

IVS11-4G＞A means a G to A transition at position -4 of intron 11